# jQuery 1.5.X Cross domain

Tags: jquery, cross-domain-policy

I would like to know if jQuery 1.5.X truly has cross-domain. I was unable to find sufficient documentation on the site and my own cross-domain tests did not work either. I am not talking about JSONP but any regular call (xml, html, json).

I do not see how jQuery can circumvent browser restrictions without use of Adobe Flash/proxy etc.

Comment: I have no idea what jQuery uses, but [`postMessage`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) actually enjoys a fair amount of cross-browser support.

Comment: you can send `http` request instead

Comment: @experimentX can you provide me with working code?

Comment: you could create a `<script>` element and point `src` to some url, but that will be `get` request. I don't know how to do `post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) you can directly use jQuery's AJAX methods to send a cross-domain AJAX request.

Unfortunately IE uses a different method which is not supported by jQuery (yet?).

Comment: CORS could work, with the (huge) caveat that you note. But unfortunately, I think this question may be like 90% of the rest - where the developer in question does not have any 'permissions' on the target domain.

Comment: @Andrew I have access to both domains. So I can modify PHP to output Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Good; Then CORS would be an option, if it were supported by more than just Firefox 3.5+ (I think maybe Chrome does, too?) But since jQuery is simply built on top of Javascript I would say no... it doesn't have that ability on its own. But anything that gives JS that ability...